# Is it good practice to use null values as a placeholder for future data?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, many-to-many

I'm working on a database that users enter in various data at different times.

Currently I have a many-to-many relationship between three tables.

tblDog: id, Name
tblOwner: id, Name
tblVet: id, name

tblDog_Owner_Vet: id, Dog_id, Owner_id, Vet_id

In a perfect world one would have all the information at one time that connects all three of these entities together but the user might have a bit of information now and then more later. Therefor I let them enter it has they get the information so entries may look like below. I am aware that usually a dog would have only one owner/vet but for sake of this question please consider it possible that a dog can have more than one owner and vet:

- 1, 1, 1, 1
- 2, 2, 2, null
- 3, 2, null, 3

They then can later go back and either add missing info or merge two rows that turn out to be associated.

Is this ok to do or are all these null values a problem? Is there another solution I may be missing?

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [Working with `NULL` Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/working-with-null.html):

> Conceptually, `NULL` means “a missing unknown value”

Therefore, it is exactly what you want in this case.

You may however like to read up on the [criticisms surrounding the use of `NULL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Criticisms), which is an age-old debate in the database world.

Answer (score 0):

I just use 0 (zero) for unset foreign key columns.
It might not make a difference in most cases but I like that it is an int type and always simpler to test against in an application.

I would have just added this as a comment but I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge disadvantage to using nulls as you suggest.   Many to many relationships, or in your case, many to many to many use composite primary keys to uniquely identify records.  As you know, primary key columns must be declared not null.

The workaround is to have records in the owner and vet tables that indicate "Not Applicable" or "none" or something like that.  Also, you would need a field also part of the primary key, in your many to many table that indicates whether the record is currently true.  For example, if you had a vetless dog in your table, you could assign the "not applicable" value to the vet field.  Then, when doggie gets a vet, you add a new record and update this record showing that it is currently false.

**Edit starts here**

From the comment, "Couldn't I just over write the "none"_id in that record with the new Vet's id?".  There is always more than one way to accomplish something.  Updating the record is one way to do it.  Another is deleting the the "none id" record and adding a new one.  To help decide, ask yourself how you intend to handle the situation where owner John decides that Dr Bloggins is no longer welcome as Fido's vet.

Also, you are not getting rid of the null to protect the foreign key constraint.  You are doing it because vet_id will be part of the primary key so it can't be null.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Quick question. I see the benefit in getting rid of the "null" in order to protect the Foreign Key constraint but what is the benefit in having the "true/false" indication. Couldn't I just over write the "none"_id in that record with the new Vet's id? Once again, I may be missing some good info here so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Foreign keys can be `NULL`.  It is only a table's primary key that cannot contain any nullable columns.  I don't see that being a problem here.

Comment: It appears to me that `tblDog_Owner_Vet.id` is the PK.  Why are you insisting upon a composite PK that will place non-NULL requirements that complicate the OP's objective of filling in e.g. `vet_id` later?

Comment: Because composite primary keys are the best way to implement many to many relationships.  They prevent duplicate records.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I got some valuable information from all of you.